# How can I follow F# Lint's suggestion to use `id`

Tags: linq, f#, static-analysis

I am comparing two lists of thangs. Since I'm more familiar with Linq than F#, I did this:

`let r1 = (rows1.Zip (rows2, fun r1 r2 -> rowComparer r1 r2)) .All (fun f -> f)`

This raises two complaints from the F# linter.

`` Lint: If `rowComparer` has no mutable arguments partially applied then the lambda can be removed.
Lint: `fun x -> x` might be able to be refactored into `id`. ``

Of these, I could understand the latter, and tried this:

`let r1 = (rows1.Zip (rows2, fun r1 r2 -> rowComparer r1 r2)) .All id`

But this made the F# compiler complain:

*This expression was expected to have type
    'System.Func<bool,bool>'

but here has type
    ''a -> 'a'*

Can someone say how this code can be more righteous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can supply the standard function `id` as an argument if you create an instance of `System.Func` with the correct number of generic type parameters from it. When employing a lambda expression, the F# compiler does that for you.

```
open System.Linq
let foo rowComparer (rows1 : seq<_>) (rows2 : seq<_>) =
    (rows1.Zip (rows2, fun r1 r2 -> rowComparer r1 r2)).All(System.Func<_,_>(id))
// val foo :
//   rowComparer:('a -> 'b -> bool) -> rows1:seq<'a> -> rows2:seq<'b> -> bool
```

Comment: Thank you. This romanced the F# compiler into getting rid of the error.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using the F# `List` or `Seq` modules instead of LINQ methods.  Then you'll be able to use F# types like `'a -> 'a` instead of `System.Func<'a, 'a>`, and you can pass `id` to the `forAll` function.  If you could post a complete example, it would be easier to give you a complete answer, but I think something like this would be roughly equivalent to what you're doing with LINQ:

```
let compare (rowComparer: ('a * 'a) -> bool) rows = 
    Seq.zip rows >> Seq.map rowComparer >> Seq.forall id
```

This creates a function that takes two sequences and compares each value in the first to the corresponding value in the second, generating a sequence of booleans.  It then returns true if all of the values in the sequence are true, otherwise it returns false.  This is achieved using function composition and partial application to build a new function with the required signature.

You can then partially apply a row comparer function to create a specialized compare function for each of your scenarios, as follows:

```
let compareEqual = compare (fun (a,b) -> a = b) 
compareEqual [0; 1; 2] [0; 1; 2] // true
compareEqual [0; 1; 2] [2; 1; 2] // false
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but it looks to me like your function chain needs the pipeline operator `|>` instead of the function composition operator `>>`.  I think you have fully applied functions (i.e. values) as the result of each one, which you need the pipeline operator for.

Comment: @Jarak Nope, they are partially applied.  `Seq.zip` takes two sequences, I have only applied the first.  `Seq.map` takes a function and a sequence, I have only applied the function.  `Seq.forall` takes a function and a sequence, I have only applied the function.  Hence, they are all still composable functions.

Comment: Oh, yes, of course, you're right!  How utterly daft of me.  Sorry to doubt you!

Comment: There's an old joke that a Real Programmer can write FORTRAN in any language. In this case, I think I was writing in C# instead of F#. Using the List and Seq modules are indeed a more idiomatic F# solution! And I think preferable. Following your advice, I came up with this, which the F# linter likes better: ```let r1 = Seq.zip rows1 rows2 |> Seq.map (fun (r1, r2) -> rowComparer r1 r2) |> Seq.forall id```